# How do i call php static method using jquery ajax in prestashop?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In tpl smarty file, I usually call the php method like follows

```html
{assign var='all_categories' value=SpecificPrice::getByProductId($product.id_product)}
                            {foreach from=$all_categories item=all}
        <pre>{$all_categories|@print_r}</pre>
        <div class="offername" style="background: red;width: 58%;color: white;font-size: 12pt;padding-top: 6px;"> {$all.offer_name} </div>
                            {/foreach}
```

But i want call the same method in  ajax

```js
SpecificPrice::getByProductId($product.id_product)
```

How do i call this method in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call any function though AJAX in PrestaShop, but you can call custom functions created by you in your controller.

You can do that by using the following procedure:

- First of all, create a front controller for your module.
- Send request to its URL and handle it in postProcess() function

More details here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+jQuery+and+Ajax